# When does the conjugation action preserve Haar measure?

Tags: group-theory, harmonic-analysis, locally-compact-groups, haar-measure

Let $H\trianglelefteq G$ be a normal closed inclusion of locally compact groups. Then $G$ acts by conjugation on $H$, thus on the one-dimensional space of Haar measures on $H$. For this action to be trivial, is it necessary for $G$ and $H$ to be unimodular? Is it sufficient? (We may as well assume, say, $G$ is second-countable for simplicity if it helps, or that it is a Lie group over a local field.)

It is evidently necessary that $H$ be unimodular. On the other hand, this is not sufficient. For example, take the inclusion $\mathbb{R}^n\trianglelefteq\mathbb{R}^n\rtimes\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$; the conjugation action on $\mathbb{R}^n$ manifests every matrix, many of which scale Lebesgue measure by a factor which is not $1$.

Edit: it is also sufficient that $H$ be compact or discrete, so it is not necessary that $G$ be unimodular. In the case $G=H\rtimes\mathrm{Aut}(H)_{\mathrm{disc}}$, I am asking how we can tell if every automorphism of $H$ scales Haar measure by $1$.

Further edit: If $H$ is open in $G$, then it does hold that unimodularity of $G$ and $H$ is necessary and sufficient.

Comment: Can one tell which groups admit an automorphism that does not preserve Haar measure?

Comment: @Ruy This is a good question. In the silly case that $H$ is a simply-connected Lie group over $\mathbb{R}$, this is equivalent to the automorphism group of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{h}$ lying in $\mathrm{SL}^{\pm}(\mathfrak{h})$, but I don't know anything more.

Comment: Had a brief discussion with a friend. If $\mathfrak{h}$ is semisimple, then every automorphism has to preserve the killing form, thus lie in $\mathrm{SL}^{\pm}(\mathfrak{h})$, so in fact every automorphism of $H$ preserves Haar measure. On the other hand, if $\mathfrak{h}$ has an Abelian factor, then of course there are automorphisms with every nonzero determinant.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your claim is true in full generality. It's also quite easy to boil down to the second countable case.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't suffice to assume that $G$ and $H$ are unimodular (but note that unimodularity of a group passes to closed normal subgroups). The following example is from Bourbaki: Let $G$ be a nonunimodular group and consider the action of $G$ on $\mathbb{R}$ given by $gs:=\Delta_G(g)s$, for $g\in G$ and $s\in \mathbb{R}$. Then $\mathbb{R}\rtimes G$ is unimodular.